# Can't separate sentences in an array into their own index or variable? Pulling data from a Sharepoint List

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, sharepoint

Let me start out by saying I'm not good at Javascript/jQuery. I'm just experimenting and figuring it out as I go along.

I'm pulling data from a Microsoft Sharepoint List and I want to assign the content to individual variables so I can reference it in various parts of the page. I successfully pulled the data, but it seems that it pulls all of it as a single array rather than individual arrays. How can I separate the content so that I can return the data in different locations?

Example: In Sharepoint the data is in a column called "Title". The content in the rows look like the following.

Video Title 1

Video Title 2

Video Title 3

When I import the data to the site I can't seem to control what is displayed.

**Test 1:** Displays the full list of content separated into their own `<p>` tag.

`$("#demo").append(
      "<p>"+NameVArray+"</p>"
    );`

Example...

`<p>Video Title 1</p>`

`<p>Video Title 2</p>`

`<p>Video Title 3</p>`

**Test 2:** When I do this it displays the last video title in the array.

`document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = NameVArray;`

Example...

Video Title 1

Video Title 2

Video Title 3 (Only this one shows up)

I like the result of test 2 and that is what I want but I can't figure out how to control what content is displayed. I want to be able to put Video Title 2 under the 2nd video I put on the site. Right now it will only do Title 3.

```js
<script type=text/javascript>
 getMyListData() ;
 function getMyListData()
 {
 var method = "GetListItems";
 var webURL = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentSite() ;
 var list = "VlibListTest";
 var fieldsToRead = "<ViewFields>"+"<FieldRef Name='Name' />" +"</ViewFields>";
 var query = "<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='True' /></OrderBy></Query>";

$().SPServices
 ({
 operation: method,
 async: false,
 webURL: webURL,
 listName: list,
 CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields Properties='True' />",
 CAMLQuery: query,
 completefunc: function (xData, Status)
 {
 $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function()
 {

 //Pulls the data from the Sharepoint List Column
 var NameV = $(this).attr("ows_Title");
  NameVArray = NameV.split();
 var PhoneV = $(this).attr("ows_VideoURL");
 var AliasV = $(this).attr("ows_VideoDescription");

//Test1
$("#demo").append(
  "<p>"+NameVArray+"</p>"
);

//Test2
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = NameVArray;

//Original Test.. Ignore..
$("#result-table").append("<tr align='middle'>" +
 "<th>"+NameV+"</th>"+
 "<th>"+PhoneV+"</th>" +
 "<th>"+AliasV+"</th>" +
 "</tr>");
 });


 }
 });
 };

</script>
```

```html
 <p style="color:pink" id="demo2"></p>

 <p style="color:red" id="demo"></p>
```

Answer (score 0):

The following code for your reference.

```
<script language="javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.SPServices/2014.02/jquery.SPServices-2014.02.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    getMyListData();
});
function getMyListData(){
    var method = "GetListItems";
    var webURL = $().SPServices.SPGetCurrentSite() ;
    var list = "VlibListTest";
    var fieldsToRead = "<ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Name' /></ViewFields>";
    var query = "<Query><OrderBy><FieldRef Name='ID' Ascending='True' /></OrderBy></Query>";

    $().SPServices({
        operation: method,
        async: false,
        webURL: webURL,
        listName: list,
        CAMLViewFields: "<ViewFields Properties='True' />",
        CAMLQuery: query,
        completefunc: function (xData, Status){
            var html="";
            $(xData.responseXML).SPFilterNode("z:row").each(function(){ 
                //Pulls the data from the Sharepoint List Column
                var NameV = $(this).attr("ows_Title");
                NameVArray = NameV.split();
                var PhoneV = $(this).attr("ows_VideoURL");
                var AliasV = $(this).attr("ows_VideoDescription");

                //Test1
                $("#demo").append(
                    "<p>"+NameVArray+"</p>"
                );

                //Test2
                html+="<p>"+NameVArray+"</p>";

                //Original Test.. Ignore..
                $("#result-table").append("<tr align='middle'>" +
                "<th>"+NameV+"</th>"+
                "<th>"+PhoneV+"</th>" +
                "<th>"+AliasV+"</th>" +
                "</tr>");
            });
            //Test2
            document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = html;
        }
    });
}
</script>

<p style="color:pink" id="demo2"></p>

<p style="color:red" id="demo"></p>
```

[image]

Comment: So that seems to display all the items in the list again. But what I am looking to do is to individually display the items in the list. So instead of having "Video Title 1" and "Video Title 2" next to each other, I want to be able to separate them and place them anywhere.